# Joomla add a "tag" field to the front end of a form

Tags: joomla, joomla3.0, joomla-extensions, chronoforms

I'm fairly new to Joomla and I need some help and guidance on adding tags to a form.  Basically, what I want to do is, have a text box where people can enter "tags", as the person types, tags that are already in the system will show up in a drop down menu (or some other way for the user to select existing tags).  Does that make since? it's a fairly common thing to do, but I can't seem to find how to do it.

Just noticed... I want to do exactly what you do with the tags field when asking a new question here.

I've tried ChronoForms, but again, can not find any information on how to add a tag field to the front-end of a form.

Thanks for any help,

Ross

Answer (score 0):

Please check the AutoCompleter demo form in CFv6 - that does what you are asking for - set Multi-Select to Yes to allow multiple tags.

Comment: Thank you, I found that and it does do what I need.  I'm having one issue. When I select multiple tags, I'm only getting 1 row in the database table (I've created a table for the form) with what looks to be a random number (the number might be all the ID's added up, so if I pick tags with the IDs 3,5,6 the number is 14).  Unfortunately, this is on a private network and I can't post code or screen shots.  One row would probably work for me if the IDs were comma delineated or something like that.  Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.